# error 438 - ActiveWorkbook.queries

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code in an Excel file:

```
Sub PullData()
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Sheet1", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents(""Link.xlsx""), null, true)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item=""Sheet1"",Kind=""Sheet""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Sheet1_Sheet,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & _
    "    #""Changed Type"""
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Sheet1;Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Range("$B$3")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Sheet1"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With End Sub


Sub ClearData() ClearData Macro

    Columns("B:C").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
     ActiveWorkbook.Queries("Sheet1").Delete 
End Sub
```

On my computer (and several other computers from my company) this file works without any problems. However, on some computers, I receive

> "Run-time error: '438': Object doesn't support this property or
>   method"

in VBA, it highlights the row `ActiveWorkbook.Queries("Sheet1").Delete`.

To explain a bit how it should work, I have an Online Excel file that contains a list with entries. There are 2 buttons, first that pulls data from that file, second one that deletes the data. I would have used only one button, that would refresh the database, but, for some reason, I keep receiving an error related to a query that already exists.

I apologize if this was asked before, but I am just begining to work with VBA and any support is more than welcomed.

Comment: When you type the dot after `ActiveWorkbook`, there should be a drop-down listing all early-bound members. Is `Queries` one of them?

Comment: Also, don’t name a query after what could be a sheet name

Comment: Yes, I have Queries in that list.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `Workbook` objects do not have a `Queries` collection. Did you maybe mean `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete`?

Comment: The VBA code is generated by a Macro command. Also, if that would have been the case (code was not correct), it wouldn't have worked on my pc. But it does, while on other machines we receive that error. Any other thoughts?